# iCarousel item disappearing when scrolling out of its height?

Tags: icarousel

I have written a program to scroll vertically in iCarousel, item appearing fine but I am facing problem while scrolling like items disappearing when I scroll out of iCarousel allocated width.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're telling iCarousel to use enough views with the option `iCarouselOptionVisibleItems`:

```c
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
    //customize carousel display
    switch (option)
    {
        case iCarouselOptionVisibleItems:
        {
            return 11;
        }
        default:
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```